# Snipcart with NextJS CORS issue with loading localisation file

Tags: next.js, snipcart

Following the [Snipcart localisation docs](https://docs.snipcart.com/v3/setup/localization), I am adding `lang="sl"`attribute in my main `<html>` tag inside the NextJS `_document.js` file.

**_document.js**

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="sl">
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

The `lang`attribute is properly rendered on the site, but Snipcart does not load sl.json translations. Instead console logs the following two errors:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cdn.snipcart.com/themes/v3.0.16/l10n/sl.json' from origin 'https://flororo.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
cdn.snipcart.com/themes/v3.0.16/l10n/sl.json:1**

**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED**

What am I doing wrong?